# Imagemagick C and C++ libraries can't be installed at same time on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04, c++, c, imagemagick

> apt install libmagickwand-dev graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat

Issue: apt won't install both packages at the same time. apt removes one when I install the other. If I attempt to install both at the same time I get errors. (please see below)

I have both C and C++ source code that uses ImageMagick, and each works individually, but requires a different package.

Here is the output of apt:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat is already the newest version (1.4+really1.3.38-1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-6.q16-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-6.q16-dev (= 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

===================================================

> apt policy graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat

```
graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat:
  Installed: 1.4+really1.3.38-1
  Candidate: 1.4+really1.3.38-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.4+really1.3.38-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

===================================================

> apt policy libmagickwand-dev

```
libmagickwand-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2
  Version table:
     8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the output of `apt policy [packagename]` for both packages.

Comment: Please use code formatting for commands and command output: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code The output is unreadable otherwise. Also fix the existing output as well

Comment: Done. Any help appreciated.